# How to know if my Magento theme needs the scriptaculous scripts?

Tags: magento

I see these default scripts are still loaded with my site on a new theme I bought:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.princessly.com/js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.princessly.com/js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.princessly.com/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.princessly.com/js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.princessly.com/js/scriptaculous/slider.js"></script>
```

Is it safe to get rid of them all as they pose significant number of requests per page view. How do I know if my theme uses them?

Thanks!

Comment: To tell the truth, I have removed whole prototype and scriptaculous from my last project **homepage**. I didn't face of any problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to eliminate the files, you could either do a code review of your templates and supplied javascript to see if they're used and remove them if they aren't.  A slightly less scientific approach is to remove each one in turn and test to see if anything breaks!

If your main concern is number of requests, use the settings under System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer to combine the JS (and/or CSS) into a single file.  You'll ship the same number of bytes, but in fewer requests.

Third party extensions such as [Fooman Speedster](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/FOOMAN/extension/457/fooman-speedster) add minification for additional performance improvement.

Comment: why suggest fooman speedster if magento has JS and css compilation built in from 1.4 versions

Comment: @AntonS The built in JS merging doesn't minify the files' contents, it only concatenates. Minification is very useful to have.

Comment: The OP seems to have performance issues. I guess Jim suggested it, because Magento only supports merging, but not minifying (which would be the next logical step to improve).

Answer (score 1):

go to

`system>configuration>developer>JavaScript Settings>Merge JavaScript Files = YES`

go to

`system>configuration>developer>CSS Settings>Merge CSS Files = YES`

and don't forget to refresh CSS and JS files cache every time you update JS files on your site

Comment: Thanks for your tip of putting jQuery before Prototype. I tried installing Fooman Speedster and it wouldn't fetch the css file, gave up on that and landed here because when i had initially tried the built in merge, it would break the site. After moving jQuery above Prototype, it works perfectly. Merging CSS breaks the layout, i'm using TWBootstrap, that seems to be the issue, will have to experiment more now. I wish i could upvote your answer, but this wont let me until i get 15reps.